# Display blank instead of first item in combobox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

Code:

```
cmbItemType.DisplayMember = "Text";
cmbItemType.ValueMember = "Value";

var items = new[] {
        new { Text = "Text1", Value = "1"},  
        new { Text = "Text2", Value = "2"}
        };

cmbItemType.DataSource = items;
```

The above code displaying two items, but how to display a *blank item* in the field. Now at load, it is displaying `Text1` without selecting. I want to display a *blank item* instead of `Text1`.

**Note**: *Blank item* should not be added to the list, so when selecting the `combobox`, I *don't want* to see a *blank item* above `Text1` display text. Thanks.

Comment: Add another item with blank text and value of -1 or 0;

Comment: Please see the _note_ in my question. I don't want to add the blank as a list. It is displaying above `Text1` when selecting the `combobox`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After you have set items as the DataSource:

```
cmbItemType.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `SelectedIndex` of `ComboBox` to *-1* which will show you ComboBox without any item selected from its items list.

```
cmbItemType.DisplayMember = "Text";
cmbItemType.ValueMember = "Value";

var items = new[] {
    new { Text = "Text1", Value = "1"},  
    new { Text = "Text2", Value = "2"}
};
cmbItemType.DataSource = items;
cmbItemType.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

*Note:*

> You cannot set the SelectedIndex of a ComboBox item to -1 if the item
>   is a data-bound item.

You may be interested in find more about the selected index [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx).